# Why Random Forest Regressor predicts single output for all the time series?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I fitted the Random Forest Regressor on my x_train (datetime series) and y_train and it predicted the y_train very well. Here is the initial part that worked:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
regressor=RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=25)
regressor.fit(x.values.reshape(-1,1),y.reshape(-1,1))  # type(x)= DatetimeIndex

pred4=regressor.predict(x.values.reshape(-1,1))
```

Then I wanted to see how are the values for the year 2023. So I generated a timeseries for 2023 and ran .predict on it:

```
year = 2023
x_23=pd.Series(pd.date_range(start=f'{year}-01-01', end=f'{year}-12-31 23:00:00', freq='H'))

pred5=regressor.predict(x_23.values.reshape(-1,1))
```

but then the prediction is the same for the whole 2023 (see the link below for the picture). Why is it so?

[real values, prediction before 2022, and prediction for 2023](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxiTD.png)

Type of x and x_23 are as follows:

```
type(x): pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex
type(x_23): pandas.core.series.Series
```

Comment: Should ask a question in the title.

Comment: Why does no one answer :( ?

Answer (score 0):

Help, please!

Everything is the same but regressor.predict gives different answers!
[See picture below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8Fgo.png)

The only thing I can think of is that I used x to fit the regressor. Is it the reason that it works for x but not for x_23?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).